# chrome.runtime.onMessage undefined in background script (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, background

I am trying to create a chrome extension, but for some reasons, sometimes, the chrome.runtime object seems incomplete, and a lot of methods are missing (including onMessage, which is the one I want).

It seems sometimes it works, sometimes not. I assumed it may be a time related issue, but I don't understand why I can't simply create a message listener on background?

My background script:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("gogo!");
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            console.log(sender.tab ?
                        "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                        "from the extension");
            if (request.type == "tab") {
                console.log("tab!");
                sendResponse({status: "ok"});
            }
        }),
    2
});
```

Where "chrome.runtime.onMessage" is undefined.

Thanks!

Edit2: I have built a much simpler prototype, and it's failing again. Now I am really confused. Here is what I have:

```
$tree
.
├── manifest.json
├── src
│   ├── background.html
│   ├── background.js
│   └── test.js
└── vendor
    └── jquery.js

2 directories, 5 files
```

manifest.json file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "test",

    "homepage_url": "http://www.test.com",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at" : "document_idle",
            "matches": ["https://www.google*"],
            "js": ["vendor/jquery.js", "src/test.js"]
        }
    ],

    "background": {
        "page": "src/background.html",
        "persistent": false
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "https://www.google*"
    ]
}
```

background.html file:

```
<script src="../vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="background.js"></script>
```

background.js file:

```
function run () {
    console.log("gogo!");
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            console.log(sender.tab ?
                        "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                        "from the extension");
            if (request.type == "tab") {
                console.log("tab!");
                sendResponse({status: "ok"});
            }
        });
}

run();
```

test.js file:

```
'use strict';

run();

function run() {
    var url = window.location.href;

    // Error if no URI
    if (!url) {
        return 1;
    }

    var uriRe = /https:\/\/www\.google.*/;
    var reParse = uriRe.exec(url);
    if (!reParse) {
        return 2;
    }

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "tab"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

I am using Chrome 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) on OSX.

Edit: Here is a screenshot of what happens the times it fails:

[image: Failure screenshot]

I want to precise again that it doesn't fail all the time (maybe 50% of the time?), which makes it even more weird and makes me believe there is a kind of "race" condition somewhere I am not aware of.

Comment: Why are you wrapping it in a timeout?

Comment: Is your background page an event page?  ("persistent": false set) If so, you shouldn't call setTimeout. If it is an event page check out the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) because there are some things to be aware of.

Comment: @DanielHerr It was just a test as I was suspecting a time related issue. It seems it was working better with a timeout, but I'm not sure about it at all.

Comment: @MichaelUpdike Thanks for the advice. I tried to set "persistent": false and the problem is still the same. I tried to set "persistent": true for testing, and it is still the same.

Comment: Do you have any devtools extension running? I know of a bug where the extension runtime  page was incorrectly classified as a non-extension page, which is fixed in Chrome 51 (currently Chrome Beta) - https://crbug.com/544182

Comment: @RobW Thanks, it has worked! I am not sure what happened, but after disabling all my extensions and re-activating them, now it works without any problem. Seems like a bug from Chrome ... anyway, thanks again :)

Comment: In my case (not OP's case), it was due to, the testing html page I have is using script injection for `main.js`. But at the same time, html page *manually refer to* the script by `<script src="../dist/main.js"></script>` -- I forgot to *remove* this line...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved: I had to disable, then re-enable all my other extensions. Seems like a bug from Chrome.

Comment: If this is indeed caused by https://crbug.com/544182, then the issue is solved by disabling all devtools extensions, opening the devtools, and then enabling the extensions again (if you want). Just disabling + re-enabling, followed by opening the devtools for the background will not solve the problem.

Comment: is this still an issue? I'm getting it today

Comment: @SuperUberDuper After 6 years this still seems to be an issue...

Comment: oh ouch!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

click the top  and set the console in extension environmint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZYfM.png)

the background just run once.you should run more to check the resutl

this is my code it wroks well:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
 function(tabId,info,tab){
  if(info.status=="complete")
   console.log("complete")
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {greeting: "inupdate"}, function(response) {
   console.log(response);
  });
 }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem.  Typing "chrome.runtime" on the console and expanding the resulting object by clicking on the little triangle showed that it had only 1 function instead of many.  In particular, chrome.runtime.onMessage was undefined.

On the page chrome://extensions I clicked the "Remove" button on the extension I was working on.  I then clicked "Load unpacked" near the top of the page and selected the directory with my extension.  After that, chrome.runtime was fully populated, and my extension ran correctly.  I have no idea why that worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think it has to do with the timeout function you are using, Google already has something called alarms which helps to schedule code to run periodically or at a specified time.

> https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms

Try that instead of timeout

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the timeout was just a test, I don't actually need it, as what I'm trying to do is an event listener.