# Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Google Chrome extension that captures screenshots of websites, and I need my `popup.js` to be able to send a message to my `background.js`. I keep getting this error: `Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined`.

Here is my current code for background.js:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({
    extensionBehavior: 'onClick',
    logIn: false
}, function(items) {
    if(items.extensionBehavior == 'onClick'){
        // When the extension icon is clicked, send a message to the content script
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            if (!request.message){
                var img;
                chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function(dataURL){
                    img = dataURL;
                    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
                        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {"message": tabs[0].url, "statusCode": 0, "image": img, "note" : request.note}, function(response){});
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        /* ... */
    }
});
```

My popup.js is sending the message properly, but my background script keeps giving me the same error. Is the `chrome.runtime` API not available inside of `chrome.storage.sync.get`? Before I added that method, the `chrome.tabs` API was working fine, and the popup is definitely sending the message (I tested it).

Comment: `chrome.runtime.onMessage` is undefined.

Comment: but I used `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` in my content script and it worked just fine. @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: No idea about these Chrome APIs, but try `console.log(chrome.runtime)` to see if it's what you expected.

Comment: [chrome.runtime.onMessage undefined in background script (chrome extension)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36692052)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was sending `tabs.sendMessage` instead of `runtime.sendMessage` with my popup.js. The tabs API sends messages to the content scripts, while the runtime API can send messages anywhere.